# Why when starting a server tcp, the form disappears?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form with a button1 and this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServerTCP s = new ServerTCP();   
}
```

And then the class serverTCP

```
public ServerTCP()
{
    TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1200);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
    listen.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
        int idgiorno = Int32.Parse(message);
        Console.WriteLine("idgiorno: " + idgiorno);
        client.Close();
     }
 }
```

The problem is that after I click on button1, the form disappears. I can see from the start bar that it's still running, but even if I click on its icon, it doesn't show it. It's like the form lose the focus.

Comment: Seems to me like you're running a continuous loop on the main thread of your program, causing to to crash and therefore you not being able to use it.

Comment: the program is a server that keeps waiting for input from clients. but i need the focus on the form because there should be another button to close the application

Comment: Then run your code on a separate thread from the main one. You can learn more about threading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do here, but I'm afraid you'll run into trouble even if you fix this bit.

First things first, as those before have said, the reason you are losing you form is because you've entered an infinite loop on you main thread. To avoid this, try using;

```
using System.Threading.Tasks
public ServerTCP()
{
    TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1200);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
    listen.Start();
    Task myTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
            int idgiorno = Int32.Parse(message);
            Console.WriteLine("idgiorno: " + idgiorno);
            client.Close();
        }
    });
    myTask.Start();
}
```

This is a lazy way to dispatch a Task to a spare thread from the pool without having to yourself create a manage one. The delegation is called a lambda expression;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397687.aspx

The problem with this is that this thread will not have access to the console resource anyway, so I'm afraid you won't see your messages.

In your code, you've written everything "procedurally". This means you've written a list of instructions assuming each step has the perquisites ready. For example;

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

If here you haven't yet received data, you'll try to initialise buffer with a 0 zero and the world will end.

Rather than try to take you through this all step by step, please watch these two youtube videos as an excellent introduction. They're not perfect, but should help get you further forward;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXFso7xSSWk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NanjpGKC2js

Really, the only robust way to approach your application is through "event driven programming", but that might be something for another day.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically the following call never returns:

```
ServerTCP s = new ServerTCP();
```

The constructor of `ServerTcp` contains an endless loop, so not only does the call never return, it also blocks the UI thread. With a blocked UI thread, window messages like WM_ACTIVATE or WM_PAINT will never be handled and thus you leave your form unusable.

You really should look into using the `TcpListener` asynchronously. [This is a good starting point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx). You will then remove your loop as well, as repeated calls to `BeginAcceptTcpClient` will keep your server running.